# how upload file using dropzone & vueJs

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, dropzone.js, vue.js

hy help me please..
I'm Using DropzoneJs & vueJs, I want upload file in vueJs using dropzone.js but doesnt work, I have try like this & msg error

```
uploadImageGallery.options.autoProcessQueue = true is not a function
uploadImageGallery.processQueue is not a function
```

how I can resolved this..?

```js
function uploadImageGallery()
{
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var uploadImageGalleryVar = $(".upload__button__news").dropzone({ 
        url: base_url+"/myRoute",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        dictCancelUpload: "",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        dictRemoveFile: "x"
    });
}

var vmGallery = new Vue({
    el: '#GalleryController',
    data: { },
    methods: {     
        AddGallery: function () {
            console.log('add');
           uploadImageGalleryVar.options.autoProcessQueue = true;
           uploadImageGalleryVar.processQueue();
        },
    },

    ready: function () { 
          uploadImageGallery();
    }

});
```

Comment: There exist also an vue wrapper for dropzone.js called vue-2-dropzone. 
I find it more convenient to use than using dropzone directly. I had the same issues with dropzone.js as you did, but I resolved it by using this package. https://rowanwins.github.io/vue-dropzone/docs/dist/#/installation 
I wrote an article about using  it here: 
https://www.the-koi.com/projects/vue-upload-images/
Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

- move the function into your methods so you can access the vm via `this`
- use `new Dropzone()` to create the Dropzone instance instead of `$().dropzone?`
- save the new instance as a vm property instead of a variable
- access it in other methods through that property

Like this:

```
var vmGallery = new Vue({

  el: '#GalleryController',
  data: {},

  methods: {
      AddGallery() {
        console.log('add');
        // access dropzone instance through vm property
        this.uploadImageGalleryVar.options.autoProcessQueue = true;
        this.uploadImageGalleryVar.processQueue();
      },

      // move function into yor methods.
      uploadImageGallery() {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        // save dropzone instance as vm property
        // use new Dropzone() to create it instead of jQuery shortcut
        this.uploadImageGalleryVar = new Dropzone($(".upload__button__news"), {
          url: base_url + "/myRoute",
          addRemoveLinks: true,
          dictCancelUpload: "",
          autoProcessQueue: false,
          dictRemoveFile: "x"
        });
      }
  },

  ready: function() {
    uploadImageGallery();
  }
});
```

That's it

Comment: thanks for your answer but still dosent work for me and for msg error still same "uploadImageGallery.options.autoProcessQueue = true is not a function,
uploadImageGallery.processQueue is not a function"

Comment: can you re-create the problem on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: rivision msg error to be "Cannot read property 'options' of undefined & processQueue of undefined "