# how to use dropzone with vuejs with out cli

Tags: html, vue.js, dropzone

Who can explain me how to use dropzone with vuejs with out use Vue CLI.

[how upload file using dropzone & vueJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294941/how-upload-file-using-dropzone-vuejs)

Comment: I think that Google can

Comment: yes that time i am sooo stuck. finally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const app = new Vue({
        el: '#newpost',
        data: {
            form: {
                title:'',
            },
            allerros: [],
            success : false,
        },
        methods : {
            onSubmit(){`

```
        },
        DzSpanclick(){
            $("#filedrag").click();
        },
        DZint() {
            let dz = document.querySelector("#filedrag");
            var previewNode = document.querySelector("#dz-template");
            previewNode.id = "";
            var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);
            Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
            this.uploadImageGalleryVar = new Dropzone(dz, {
                url:"{$base_dir}post",
                parallelUploads: 100,
                paramName: "file",
                params: { do: "imageupload" },
                thumbnailWidth: 600,
                thumbnailHeight: 600,
                autoProcessQueue: false,
                acceptedFiles:"image/*",
                previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
                uploadMultiple: false,
                maxFiles: 8,
                maxFilesize: 5,
                autoDiscover : false,
                previewsContainer: "#previews",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/javascript" }
            });
        },

    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.DZint();
    }

});
```

Comment: I am glad you solve it. You can mark it as the answer I guess.